# PoshGit in powershell ise

Tags: powershell, posh-git

I have poshgit working fine from the powershell console but when I'm trying to use it within the ise it doesn't work. At least when I'm trying to fetch it doesn't prompt me to enter the username (I'm not using the winstore or similar) and just freezed.

I have seen that you have to update the ise profile in order to make it work there as well so what I tried to do is run the install.psi which have set the profile to

```
# Load posh-git example profile
. 'C:\tools\poshgit\dahlbyk-posh-git-f948f5a\profile.example.ps1'
```

But that's different to the one created for the other profile, but even copying the one there in the ise one doesn't work

Thanks

EDIT: Found this, and that's why I tried to run install.ps1 but didn't work [here](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/107)

EDIT2: It is not only fetch that doesn't work properly, I face the problem [explained here](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/109) as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ISE with interactive console applications - applications that require you to type in stuff.

Best solution - which works for me - is to use ConEmu (a console emulator) with the PSReadLine module (module which provides intellisense).